# Angular 6 app with multiple projects. How to run all spec files? ng test runs only first project

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular6, wallaby.js, nrwl

I'm working on an app which uses multiple projects. As mentioned, only the first project's spec.ts files are executed. 
It will be much appreciated if I can see a monorepo which has multiple projects, capable of executing all specs, using:

- angular 6
- karma, jasmine
- nrwl/nx 6
- wallaby.js (if possible)

Related to (github):

- [#514](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/514)
- [#518](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/518)
- [#529](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/529)